# Unable to generate android apk file through Ionic Project

Tags: android, json, node.js, ionic-framework

I recently buy one ionic project, i had tried a lot to generate APK file but unable to successful.

> First i download the file and run cmd.goto the files directory.
> i run the command **ionic platform add android** , bit it says

[After Executing ionic platform add android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAU0j.png)

if i rename ionic.project to `ionic.config.json` and again execute **ionic platform add android** it says * Looks like a fresh checkout! No ./node_modules directory found. Would you like to install proj
ect dependencies?*

After installing npm i execute **ionic build --release android** but it does nothing and gives me warning
[WARN] Not performing Ionic build for project type: ionic1.
[WARN] Error with .\www\lib\ionic\version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND, trying .\bower.json.
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJMLU.png)

Please help me out i am badly stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after updating.
`ionic lib update` does not work if there is no www/lib/ionic.

You can create it though by copying manually from node_modules/ionic-sdk/release.

This removed the FILE_NOT_FOUND errors for me.